# Prevent scipy from multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm using `scipy` to compute rotations of vectors. The following code is a minimal one that reproduces my problem. It is not necessarily correct mathematically.

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.linalg import expm

axis = np.array([5.0, 8.0, -2.0])
axis = axis/(np.sum(axis**2)**0.5)

theta = 0.001


for t in range(1000000):
    cx = np.cross(np.eye(3), axis*theta)
    M0 = expm(cx)
    cx = np.dot(M0, cx) 

print cx
```

My problem is that running this code takes up 300% of my CPU, that is, running on 3 cores. I believe this is due to the `scipy.linalg.expm` function because the `numpy` functions alone only used up to 100%. My question is, how to configure `scipy` to only use a single core?

I don't remember ever linking it against any linalg library, but here are my configs:

```
#numpy
numpy.__config__.show()
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE


#scipy
scipy.__config__.show()
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = f77
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = f77
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = f77
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = f77
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely multithreading on the C level by openblas, not python-level multiprocessing. Try setting the env variable OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1

Comment: yes, `export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1` solved the problem. thank you.